# css :not selector isn't working

Tags: html, css

The following selector doesn't work:

```
*:not(.ignore-mobile) [class^="cell"]{width:100%;}
```

On my `header` element:

```
<header class="nav ignore-mobile">
```

The header child divs with class `cell` still show width 100%.

Any idea why?

More info:

I am using Chrome 40 on a desktop.

Comment: you need to state what browsers/devices are you using (as perhaps it is not supported syntax on that versions?)

Comment: You need to provide us with more context.

Comment: Sorry about that, I editted my answer

Comment: If you need more, let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't need that extra info as the answer should be browser agnostic for the most part. See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `.ignore-mobile` in your css selector in quotes like this:

```
*:not(".ignore-mobile") [class^="cell"]{width:100%;}
```

See jsfiddles below for contrast:

In quotes:
http://jsfiddle.net/1jfdukd1/1/

Not in quotes:
http://jsfiddle.net/1jfdukd1/2/

Comment: Winhowes, you are right, this is the solution. However, I don't understand why most selectors work without quotes. Is it because of the dash (-) ?

Comment: It seems that when `:not()` is used on its own or with only `*` in front of it, it needs to be in quotes. If however you did something like `header:not(.ignore-mobile) ...` it would not need to be in quotes.  Why this is, I do not know, and is a good question

Comment: It does not work for me with quotes. Without quotes it is red.

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block elements, so they automatically gets 100% width. If you set all divs widths to 50%, your code will work.

However, it's kind of terrible to use both *, which is slow as hell, and :not that only should be used when you are out of options. Always try to make short, simple and including css classing instead of complicated excluding classes.

In this case the obvious chouse would be to just use div { width: 50%; } .ignore-mobile .no-cell { width: 100%; }

Here is a working copy of your bad code :)

```css
*:not(.ignore-mobile) [class^="cell"] {
  width:100%;
}

div {
  background: red;
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="nav ignore-mobile">
  <div class="cell">Test</div>
  <div>Test2</div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tony, I am not actually using * in my code, this was just a test to ensure that I am targetting all elements (since it wasn't working, I tried all options). Also, I know divs are block elements. the cell div is floated and part of a grid layout, as you could have guessed...